# How is the value of an integral gives an opposite sign for the same value when the upper and lower limits are switched?

Tags: calculus

Say I have [this integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQeC.png) (1st):

- What is exactly happening when we switch the upper and lower limits like [this integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7DPX.png) (2nd)?
- How did we get the negative sign in the second integral, even though the value was already given but the function itself is not in the first integral?

(Please show steps to understand what happened)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!
See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: @Frentos Thanks! I'll check it out! Any ideas about my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamental theorem of calculus

$\int^a_bf(x)dx =F(a)-F(b)$

thus if you switch the bounds $(F(a)-F(b)) = -(F(b)-F(a))$